How to use transfer api for fund transfer from existing plaid user to outside plaid user within USA
How to use transfer api for fund transfer from existing plaid user to outside plaid user, or if I am missing something then whats the best approach to achieve this. We have a use case where our customer 1 would send money to another customer 2 who is not verified or outside of our system but cusotmer 2 bank details and basic details are available with us like bank details , name , address etc. It should have ACH, wire, fednow and rtp supports.

This use case is an example of what is considered a Transfer Platform Payments use case:
https://plaid.com/docs/transfer/application/#what-is-a-platform
As noted in the linked documentation, Platform Payments use case support is currently in a closed beta and not generally available, so unless you are in the beta program, this is not currently possible via Transfer.

Thank you for the response @Alex. In this scenario, we have control over the sender's actions, but not over the receiver's. Consider a situation where you're transferring money to a friend using a Plaid transfer service. You possess your friend's bank details, including their name, etc. However, system lack essential Plaid-specific identifiers such as the receiver's public token, access token, or account ID. Under these circumstances, the transfer process encounters a challenge since the receiver isn't expected to interact directly with Plaid.
